# Mock Angular Router with Spectator

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine, angular-spectator, ng-mocks

I am using [Spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator) to write my Angular 8 tests and [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) to run them. I am new to frontend unit testing, so I may have overlooked something simple; any ideas are welcome.

I have the following method (in Typescript) that returns a boolean, based on whether the current URL matches a set of paths or not (excluding queryParams and fragments):

```
// custom-breadcrumb.component.ts

private blacklistedPaths: string[] = [''];

constructor(private router: Router) {
}

hideBreadcrumb(): boolean {
    let primaryUrlSegmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.children['primary'];
    if(primaryUrlSegmentGroup == null){
        return true;
    }
    let urlPath = primaryUrlSegmentGroup.segments.map((segment: UrlSegment) => segment.path).join('/');
    return this.blacklistedPaths.some((path: string) => path === urlPath);
}
```

and

```
// custom-breadcrumb.component.html

<xng-breadcrumb [hidden]="hideBreadcrumb()">
    <ng-container *xngBreadcrumbItem="let breadcrumb">
        ...
    </ng-container>
</xng-breadcrumb>
```

I now want to write tests with Spectator that will validate the boolean return value based on a couple of possible urls. In Java I would emulate the `Router` with a mock object and perform something along the lines of:

```
when(mockObject.performMethod()).thenReturn(myReturnValue);
```

How do I create a mock for the `Router`?  And how do I define the return values for `this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.children['primary']`?

This is what I currently have:

```
// custom-breadcrumb.component.spec.ts

import {SpectatorRouting, createRoutingFactory} from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';

describe('CustomBreadcrumbComponent', () => {
    let spectator: SpectatorRouting<CustomBreadcrumbComponent>;
    const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
        component: CustomBreadcrumbComponent,
        declarations: [
            MockComponent(BreadcrumbComponent),
            MockPipe(CapitalizePipe)
        ],
        routes: [{path: ''}]  // I don't think this works
    });

    beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

    it('hideBreadcrumb - hide on homepage', () => {
        // TODO set url path to ''
        expect(spectator.component.hideBreadcrumb()).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('hideBreadcrumb - show on a page other than homepage', () => {
        //TODO set url path to 'test' for example
        expect(spectator.component.hideBreadcrumb()).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

I know that `createRoutingFactory` supplies a `ActivatedRouteStub` out of the box, but I haven't been able to do anything meaningful with it.

PS: I added karma as a tag as it may have the same solution, but do correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression that `spectator.router` was returning me a mock, while I had to use `spectator.get<Router>(Router)` to get it. The other problem I had was that the `hideBreadcrumb` method in the html template was being loaded at component creation while I did not have the chance yet to mock the `Router`. This is how I solved it:

Set `detectChanges` to false to prevent the html template and ngOnInit from being loaded when I create the spectator component like so:

```
let spectator: SpectatorRouting<CustomBreadcrumbComponent>;
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    detectChanges: false,
    component: CustomBreadcrumbComponent,
    declarations: [ ... ]
});

beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent()
});
```

Now it won't call `hideBreadcrumb()` yet, which allows for successful creation of the spectator.

My test is this:

```
it('hideBreadcrumb - hide on homepage', () => {
    let routerMock = spectator.get<Router>(Router);
    routerMock.parseUrl.andReturn({root: {children: {'primary': {segments: [{path: ''}]}}}});
    spectator.detectChanges();

    expect(spectator.component.hideBreadcrumb()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I retrieve a mock from the spectator with `spectator.get<Router>(Router)` and I mock the return value of the `parseUrl` method. I now allow the html template and `ngOnInit` progression by setting `spectator.detectChanges()`.